# Не получается использовать метод внутри класса через this

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Все привет,у меня есть сервер на nodejs в котором есть класс PaymentController .
В нем 1 из методов создает токен который мне нужен в другом методе этого же класса. Если я использую его просто на сервере, то я могу обратиться к нему через this ,а если я обращаюсь к нему с фронта при помощи restApi, то я получаю "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined"

Я использую nodeJs в связке с express и это выглядит так

```
 app.post("/changePrice", express.json(),PaymentController.updatePrice);
    
        class dgsController {
      constructor() {
        this.getToken = this.getToken.bind(this);
      }
    
      async getToken() {
        const date = Date.now();
        const sign = sha256(`${process.env.ApiKey}${date}`);
        const data = {
          seller_id: process.env.id,
          timestamp: date,
          sign: sign,
        };
        console.log(data);
        const token = await axios
          .post("getTokenUrl", data)
          .then((resp) => resp.data.token);
    
        return token;
      }
    
      async updatePrice(req, res) {
        console.log(await this.getToken());
}
```

Мне подсказали, что нужно забиндить этот метод в конструкторе ,но видимо я что-то сделал нет так..

Есть идеи?

Comment: За`bind`и этот метод в конструкторе класса. `this.PaymentController = this.PaymentController.bind(this)`